# strange jQuery Mobile listview not fully refreshing

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with a jQuery Mobile listview not refreshing, however only in one extremely particular instance. The issue occurs when I'm testing my app on an android phone (specifically a Google Nexus). The issue occurs after my listview loads properly from view 1 to view 2. I then go to view 3. When I go from view 3 to view 2 the listview does not entirely load. What I mean by this is that it does actually load my code properly, however it is never displayed until I attempt to select one of the rows. Once I select one of the rows they all suddenly appear. I am creating my listview by appending html with javascript in `document.ready()`. I know this is said to be bad practice currently, however when I use the jQuery suggested method of `document.bind('pageinit')` it will work from 3 to 2 however everytime I leave view 2 `document.bind('pageinit')` is fired again. Is there anyway around this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried **$('#your-list-id').listview('refresh');** ?

Comment: how about a link or some code?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important things to realize when developing with jQuery Mobile is that your javascript isn't unloaded when navigating between pages. What this in effect means is that when you use `.bind()` (or `.on()`, which is the [preferred way](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)) it is not unbound when leaving the page. This means you will have to manage this yourself.

After some struggling I found the following solution to work best for me. Load all your javascript in the `<head>` and create a separate javascript file which handles things like bindings. These files aren't unloaded by page navigations. An outline of this file is as follows.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(event){
    currentPageId = $(event.target).attr("id");
    //Give every <div data-role="page"> an id and switch on it.
    switch (currentPageId) {
        case "index":
            loadIndex();
            break;
        case "fooPage":
            loadFooPage();
            break;
        case "barPage":
            loadBarPage();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

On each pageload you will bind new functions you want to that page in the following way:

```
function loadIndex(){
    $(document).one("pageshow", function pageshow(event){
        console.log("Entered the index");
        $(window).on("scrollstart", someFunction);

        //Unbind everything when a new page is loaded.            
        $(document).one("pagebeforeshow", function pagebeforeshow(event){
            console.log("Exited the index")
            $(window).off("scrollstart", someFunction);
        });
    });
}
```

Do this for every page you want to bind stuff to. When this is done you can execute javascript functions as you are used to, because they are loaded and unloaded on each page show.