# Loading jQuery Mobile page from navbar doesn't load javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I was able to reference [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540219/jquery-mobile-change-page-doesnt-load-js-files) to realize that JS scripts needed to be nested within the data-role page element in order to get it to load when the page is accessed by AJAX. But for a code like the following, which allows a user to swipe left and right *among* pages, you really can't just load the script for page 1 (in other words, it needs to access all of the data-role=page elements). What recourse does one have if you access this page via AJAX?

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function(){
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
    $.mobile.changePage(nextpage,{transition: "slide", reverse:false}, false, true);
    }
    });
    $('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function(){
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
    $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide",
    reverse: true}, true, true);
    }
```

Demo:
Click on the Danger tab (doesn't work even though it sends you to multipage.php): 
https://stanford.edu/~rakasaka/cgi-bin/cs147/week5/index.php

Alternatively, reload the multipage.php and swipe left and right:
https://stanford.edu/~rakasaka/cgi-bin/cs147/week5/multipage.php

It should work, because the JS is loaded.

Comment: Maybe binding and unbinding between pages may help. I made an answer for this once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813909/strange-jquery-mobile-listview-not-fully-refreshing/12642135#12642135.